# mongoose/javascript: Can't update collection in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my db schema

```js
let couponId = Schema({
    RestaurantId: { type: String },
    RestaurantName: { type: String },
    RestaurantLocation: { type: String },
    AssignedTo: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    CouponValue: { type: [String] }
});
```

I want to update the `AssignedTo` field with a value of array of objects with a dynamic key and a value. I am performing this query

```js
CouponId.findOne({
  "RestaurantId": resId
}, (err, restaurant) => {

  value.push({
    [userNumber]: restaurant.CouponValue[0]
  });
  console.log(value);
  restaurant.update({
    "RestaurantId": resId
  }, {
    $set: {
      "AssignedTo": value
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("updated");
    }
  });
});
```

The query, when executed, is giving the result of `updated` in console but its not getting updated in db. If this query is converted to MongoShell query and executed, it gives the result and collection is getting updated, where mongoShell query i am running is

`db.couponids.update({"RestaurantId" : "1234"},{$set:{"AssignedTo":[{"1234":"2345"}]}});`

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`restaurant` is the output from the first collection and doesn't have any update function in it... So, You need to keep the same collection name from which you have done `findOne`

```
CouponId.update({
    "RestaurantId": resId
  }, {
    $set: {
      "AssignedTo": value
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("updated");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Worked. Thank You.